# Delayed Job passenger production undefined method error

Tags: passenger, actionmailer, delayed-job

I am using delayed job version 2.1.4 with action mailer 3.0.8 to send my emails in background.

```
UserMailer.delay.newsletter(email)
```

It works with me fine in development and production Rails **console**.

But when it is called from my live **production passenger server**, it creates DJ but when this DJ runs, it throws

```
{undefined method `newsletter' for #<Class:0xc08afa0>
```

I think the problem

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with rails/passenger in production mode with **class methods**

So, I made a work around solution... I will try to call **instance** method and avoid to call **class** method.

Lets see an example; assuming I need to call the following method in background..

```
UserMailer.deliver_newsletter(email)
```

Then, I created a new class DelayClassMethod

```
class DelayClassMethod
  def initialize(receiver_name, method_name, options={})
    @receiver_name = receiver_name
    @method_name = method_name
    @parameters = options[:params] || []
  end

  def perform
    eval(@receiver_name).send(@method_name, *@parameters)
  end
end
```

and can run the method in background now by

```
DelayClassMethod.new("UserMailer", "deliver_newsletter", :params=>[email]).delay
```

So, I am running an **instance** method now in background which will run the **class** method.

Another example..

Assume I want to run

```
Product.list_all_by_user_and_category(user, category).delay
```

Then it can be run by

```
DelayClassMethod.new("Product", "list_all_by_user_and_category", :params => [user, category]).delay
```

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that you have multiple versions of the delayed_job in production.  Are you using bundler to start your delayed job process?

I would recommend when doing [bundle install in production](http://gembundler.com/deploying.html), I would use the --binstubs flag to generate a wrapper around the delayed_job and use that executable to start the jobs.

Comment: no, i am having only one version. I tried bundle exec rake jobs:work but still the same error.